# Doxygen isn't generating descriptions for files

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I am writng the documentation for a project with Doxygen, and everything works more or less as expected, except for the description of the files. In the begining of the files I have:

```
/**
  @file $relPath
  @copyright $copyright
  @author dcasado
  @brief Description test
*/
```

But then when opening the HTML and accessing the File List, none of the files have a description. Doxygen properly understands the `/** */` syntax of that document, as it hiddes that part of the code when accessing the source code of the file.

The @brief argument works fine with classes and funcions, it's only failing with files.

My files are .ctl, but mapped to .cpp type.

As I cannot copy here all the doxyfile, I'm copying only the configs I changed from the default values:

```
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = D:/DCasado/Desktop
TAB_SIZE               = 2
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = ctl=c++
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
INPUT                  = C:/WinCC_OA_Proj/NaturgyCCR/NTGY_sys1/NTGYProj_sys1/scripts
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
```

I tried changing configs and reading all the configs documentation, but anything appears to be a solution. I also tried changing `@brief` for `\brief` and adding *'s at the beggining of each line. I know they are not necessary, but I really cannot undertsand why it's not working at all.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What is in $relpath and in $copyright? When the `\file` command is in the same file as the file it documents it is not necessary.

Comment: @albert Doxygen's version is 1.9.8. I think both variables are empty. I deleted both \file and \copyright. They were both automatically as WinCC OA files are created by default like this

Comment: and what happens now ?

Comment: the same as before, nothing

Comment: Did you remove the `$relPath`, as when it is present you should get a warning like "warning: the name 'relPath' supplied as the argument in the \file statement is not an input file". I also assume that the `ctl` file is in the directory `C:/WinCC_OA_Proj/NaturgyCCR/NTGY_sys1/NTGYProj_sys1/scripts`. Probably I found the problem, it looks like you didn't add `*.stl` to the `FILE_PATTERNS` setting.

Comment: The header now looks like this:
`/** * \author dcasado * \brief Brief description test*/`

The extension is ctl, no stl. Did you mean that? Or is `.stl` a different thing I don't know

Comment: Sorry just a typo in my comment, I meant `*.ctl`.

Comment: I don't know why is not that config shown in the changed configs log, but it's included. `.ctl` files are included and shown, so the `FILE_PATTERNS` is working as expected, as that type of files were not included before adding them through that conf. It's only the description what is not shown. Even the descriptions of the classes, functions and variables are shown, only happening the issue with the file description

Comment: You wrote: The header now looks like this: `/** * \author dcasado * \brief Brief description test*/` so looks like the `\file` is gone as well, try `/** \file * \author dcasado * \brief Brief description test*/`

Comment: Nice, you find the problem. `\file $relPath` was the problem. Using just `\file`, followed by a `\brief` line, works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @albert pointed on the comments, the problem was the `$relPath` variable. It was not defined and, apparently, it was blocking the proper interpretation of the rest part. So just by deleting that variable, it started to work out again. The result is:

```
/**
  @file
  @copyright $copyright
  @author dcasado
  @brief Description test
*/
```